# Webmin: Scheduled Cron Jobs page not working after wget script crashed - loads an external website instead

Tags: cron, ubuntu-server, webmin

A cron job running a PHP script with a heavy wget crawler crashed and now I am unable to load the page "Scheduled Cron Jobs" in Webmin.

Instead of listing the cron jobs, it directly loads parts of an external website (probably a site my wget crawler was trying to process when it crashed).

I have tried to access Webmin using several browsers. I have rebooted apache, hard rebooted the server, restarted cron and checked all running processes, but are not able to find the cause. Looking at the memory use of my Ubuntu-server, it seems like the PHP script is still running somehow - but I am not able to find it anywhere.

What could be causing the Scheduled Cron Jobs page to not work?

Is there a cache file I should clear or anything else I can restart to make it work again? Appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: I have also disabled the job using crontab -e and commenting it out in the terminal. But it doesn't help.

Comment: Now I got access! I had to change Webmin theme (Webmin - Change Language and Theme). So apparently there is a cached file or something that messes up the cron page on the normal theme.

Comment: Tried to delete the theme and re-install it - didn't work. Still having the same issue on the Scheduled Cron Jobs page. Guess I just have to use the old looking theme...